# Kicad 7 - Automatically change all traces widths

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, trace

In my pcb layout, I have two different trace widths.
Both of these have to be changed.

Is there a way to do this automatically?
Meaning, all trace widths of size X should become Y, while all trace widths of size Z, should become O.

Since the new Kicad also supports python, maybe there is a way to do this automatically, instead of the labor of manually changing every single trace on the board.

Answer (score 3):

The [PCB file is ASCII format](https://dev-docs.kicad.org/en/file-formats/sexpr-pcb/), so you can open it with notepad and use find and replace on string that match for example:

*") (width X) (layer "F.Cu") ("*

and replace with

*") (width Y) (layer "F.Cu") ("*